# Encrypted home and power failure

Tags: encryption

If when using an encrypted home (with eCryptFs) my system has a power failure is it more likely to cause data loss than it would if it wasn't encrypted? At what extent?

What about a system freeze?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not your home folder is encrypted shouldn't affect your data loss one way or another. However, having an encrypted home directory makes it a lot harder to recover data from a Live CD. If you lose the password that you got after installing Ubuntu that allows you to unencrypt the directory, then your chances of getting data out of the folder are slim to none. So, therefore, it is good to always backup frequently. Ubuntu 11.10 comes with a nice built in backup utility, supporting backup to an Ftp server, external hard drive, Ubuntu One, etc. EcryptFs writes the data directly to disc, and there shouldn't be any data loss problems.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know that if I loose the password its "bye bye data". My question is because, at least with some encryption applications, unencrypted data is stored for some time in memory and not immediately encrypted and written to disk. So after saving a file it does not go immediately to disk. At least that's what I read somewhere (can't find the source :S). Maybe eCryptFs does not work this way?

Comment: Thanks for saying Thanks. No, eCryptFs should write the data directly to disk. you shouldn't have any problems. and your risk of data loss is low.

Comment: Nice :) Can you update your answer with that info so I can mark it as Answer?

Comment: Sure, 1 second.

Comment: There, I added it to my answer.